# Constructing the reflected pyramid from a given perspective image

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

[image]

You're given the perspective image of an inverted pyramid shown above.  $ABCD$ and $EFGH$ represent squares that lie in parallel planes.  Point $N$ is the center of $ABCD$ and $M$ is the center of $EFGH$.
Segment $NP$ is orthogonal to the plane of $ABCD$.  You want to construct an identical pyramid whose base is centered at point $P$, and its apex is point $N$, and its base sides are parallel to the base sides of the original pyramid.

How can you construct the reflected pyramid ?

**Details and Assumptions:**

You have the $2D$ coordinates (in the image) of all the blue points $A$ through $H$.  And that's all you have.

Comment: Think about figure wich contains ABCDS and congruent A'B'C'D'N and pretty similar to both of them

Comment: Are you looking to really construct this second pyramid using compass and straightedge, as the title suggests? If so, knowing the coordinates of the blue points might be relevant since you need to encoder these numbers somehow in your construction. Or are you looking for a computation, where you feed in the world coordinates and picture coordinates that you know and get the picture coordinates you don't know as a result?

Comment: @MvG The world coordinates of the blue points are not known.  Only the 2D coordinates of the blue points in the image is known.

Comment: It's possible to do it if the projection plane is parallel to the axis of the pyramid. Otherwise I don't think it can be constructed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A'B'C'D'$ be the reflected base. Diagonals $AC$, $EG$ and $A'C'$ meet at the same vanishing point, hence line $A'C'$ through $P$ can be constructed. And in the same way on can construct line $B'D'$.

If the plane of the image is parallel to the axis of the pyramid, then line $PN$ is parallel to $AA'$, $BB'$ etc. and that allows points $A'B'C'D'$ to be constructed.

[image]

If the plane of the image is not parallel to the axis of the pyramid then it is not possible to construct $A'B'C'D'$, unless a line parallel to $PN$ is given in the image. Failing that, we could choose at will a vanishing point $Q$ on the extension of $NP$ and draw $AA'$, $BB'$ etc. concurring to $Q$: the resulting quadrilateral $A'B'C'D'$ could be a possible base for the reflected pyramid.